# Is there a way to get proper block object of pyethereum with RPC?

Tags: web3js, pyethereum, python, pyethapp

I am running a geth node and I would like to connect to the node with python and get instance of the Block class:

https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/blocks.py#L164

is there some existing solution to this? 
I was playing with web3.py but that does only return result as dictionary...